# How do I perform unique self join with intersection on a table

Tags: sql-server

How do I perform unique self join on a table

```
TableA
col1 col2
1    a
1    b
1    c
2    a
2    b
3    a
3    b
3    d
```

col 1 represents user, col 2 represents interest of that user
what I want is
A unique combination of the two.
1,2 but not (2,1),(1,1), (2,2)
with an intersection of interest.

```
Desired result
2,1 a
2,1 b
3,1 a
3,1 b
3,2 a
3,2 b
```

Note : for challenge reasons procedures functions not allowed. You may answer that way.

Comment: If you want to delimit integers you need at least one function. It's impossible without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inequality condition in the join to get the right raw data:

```
select a2.col1, a1.col1, a1.col2
from TableA a1
join TableA a2 on a1.col2 = a2.col2 and a1.col1 < a2.col1
order by a2.col1, a1.col1, a1.col2
```

See it work here:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4914d/2

This gives the correct results without functions, but does not combine the two `col1` values into one comma-separated field. For that part, while some databases allow an implicit conversion, Sql Server **will** require a `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` function to turn the numeric (int) data into text, and there's no way around it. However, from a database perspective, this is work that is better done in client code anyway.